# How can I keep my iterable value in Python?

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I have a function to identify and separate words and numbers from a given string, however, my iterable(i) isn't skipping where it should, and I'm having redundant results:

```
SPACES = [' ', '\n', '\t', '\v', '\f', '\r']
OPERATORS = "%*/+-!^="
DIGITS = '0123456789'
LETTERS = '_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
PARENTHESIS = '()'
return_list = []
test=''
for i in range(len(list_a)):
    print(i)
    if i in SPACES:
        print('space')
    elif list_a[i] in OPERATORS:
        return_list.append(list_a[i])
    elif list_a[i] in DIGITS or list_a[i] == POINT:
        while list_a[i] in DIGITS or list_a[i] == POINT:
            test=test+list_a[i]
            i+=1
        return_list.append(test)
        test=''
        continue
    elif list_a[i] in LETTERS:
        while list_a[i] in LETTERS or list_a[i] in DIGITS:
            test = test+list_a[i]
            i+=1
        return_list.append(test)
        test=''
        continue
    elif list_a[i] in PARENTHESIS:
        return_list.append(list_a[i])
return return_list
```

for a string `abcde 123 (`, I'm getting this return:

```
['abcde', 'bcde', 'cde', 'de', 'e', '123', '23', '3', '(']
```

how can I get:

```
['abcde', '123','(']
```

Comment: `i` is an integer, i.e. your counter, not an iterable. BTW, to get `['abcde', '123','(']` you can do `list_a.split()`, assuming `list_a` is a string

Comment: Maybe you should give the complete code including `SPACES` `OPERATORS` etc..

Comment: I can't use split() because not all elements are separated...

Comment: OK then use regular expressions, do not re-invent the wheel (unless it's for training purposes)

Comment: You can use split() with any character: '1.2 + 5'.split('.') returns ['1', '2 + 5']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updates on i in the while loops do not affect the i values in the for loops.
The for loop iterates i over [0,1,2,...]. At the start of the second iteration, no mater what value i is, it will be set back to the second value predefined in the for loop (i.e. 1). And so on.
Try replacing the first for loop by a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to set up a context variable that records whether the 'cursor' (i.e. the position of the loop in the text string) is currently within a word, a number, or neither. If within a word or number, the next character gets added to the previous item in the list rather than appended as a new item.

```
def parse_text(text):
    context = None
    r = []
    for ch in text:
        if ((context == 'number' and ch in DIGITS + POINT) or
            (context == 'word' and ch in LETTERS + DIGITS)):
            r[-1] += ch
            continue
        if ch in OPERATORS + PARENTHESIS + DIGITS + LETTERS:
            r.append(ch)
        context = None
        if ch in DIGITS:
            context = 'number'
        elif ch in LETTERS:
            context = 'word'
    return r
```